# Script stops working as soon as it tries to `include('facebook.php')`

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have this small piece of code, I know it does nothing but I don't know why it does even less.

It echoes the first image, then after trying to include facebook.php everything stops. Not only FB specific instructions, but everything.

I dug through Google and didn't find a satisfying answer. Has anyone had similar problems?

The Facebook SDK version is the latest one (3.0.2 I think), and includes work fine for my other files.

```
<?php

echo "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/Losiowaty/picture\">";

require_once 'library/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
//$facebook = new Facebook(array(
//'appId'  => '15xxxxxxxxxxx',
//'secret' => '2d38xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4',
//));

echo "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/Losiowaty/picture\">";

?>
```

EDIT : 
SOLVED! -> Facebook API requires cURL and my server didn't have it ;] Thanks everyone for comments and ideas :)

Comment: check your webservers error log, maybe you'll find a message there that tells you why the script execution stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned a long time ego via an edit to the question :

> Facebook API requires cURL and my server didn't have it ;] Thanks
>   everyone for comments and ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

require_once will halt the script if it fails. This is expected behavior. Is library/facebook.php accessible from your script? It doesn't seem to be. One quick and dirty solution would be to just uset [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) and add the library to your path variable at the start of your script. Something like this:

```
$lib_path = "/var/lib/php/facebook-sdk";

$path = get_include_path();
set_include_path($path . PATH_SEPARATOR . $lib);
```

Comment: It is. "Library" is a subdir of the one where index.php is located. Moving them to the same dir didn't help... Still trying ;]

Comment: "Library" and "library" are completely different directories, on my OS.

Comment: I know, a typo hero on SO. Nevertheless, as I said even if all the files are in the same dir, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Have you tried changing it to absolute path in your require_once statement?